# Aligning icon/image next to input box

Tags: html, forms, css, icons, alignment

Ive got the following form where Im trying to have an icon (the paper clip) next to the top row of buttons. The top row is two buttons aligned next to each other in a group. Using UIKit for this.

[image]

What Im struggling is to align the icon next to the buttons. Just trying to float it so it shouldnt resize anything. Excerpt of what i have done is also given however its done in React render so not pure html.

```
        <div className="uk-margin-large-top">
            <form id={"form_element_"} className="uk-form uk-width-4-5 uk-align-center">
                <fieldset>
                    <div className="uk-form-row textbox-margin">
                        <label htmlFor={"label_"} className={r.requiredClass}>{this.props.fieldLabel}</label>
                        <div className={"uk-form-controls uk-button-group uk-display-block"} data-uk-button-radio>
                            {buttons}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <i className="uk-icon-small uk-icon-paperclip"></i>
        </div>
```

scss is given below,

```
.uk-margin-large-top {
    margin-top: 50px !important;
}

.uk-align-center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
[class*="uk-align-"] {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.uk-width-4-5, .uk-width-8-10 {
    width: 80%;
}
[class*="uk-width"] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}

.uk-display-block {
    display: block !important;
}

.uk-button-group {
    font-size: 0;
}

.uk-icon-small {
    font-size: 150%;
    vertical-align: -10%;
}
```

What is the best way to vertical centre this icon to the right of the two buttons at the top in css3 ?

Comment: Ya I don't have a way to recreate your uikit or whatever, but you have a block level element (form) and an inline element (i) and they both should be `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

I don't (yet) understand your HTML but you could try CSS positioning or the pseudo-element :before and :after.

maybe add the class `uk-icon-small uk-icon-paperclip` to the button you are trying to get it next to.